# how to stop cache from interfering with application logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use Rails 4 cache digests in my app, but am finding that it interferes with a lot of application logic. For example, in this code, the links that are supposed to only be revealed where the current_user's id matches `@user.id` aren't working properly when I have the cache surrounding the code. Those links are visible to anyone who views the page.

```
<% cache @languages do %>
   <% for language in @languages%>

    <tr>
      <td><%= language.name %> </td>


      <% if current_user && current_user.id == @user.id %>
       <td><%= link_to  "edit", {:controller => 'lawyer_profiles', :action =>'show', :language_id =>"#{language.id}"}, {:class => "editarea #{language.id}"}%></td>
      <td><%= link_to "destroy", language, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
     <% end %>
    </tr>


    <% end %>


 <% end %>
```

In this code, the cache was interfering with the @question instance variable. For example, due to the presence of the cache, when I clicked on the link to "Add An Answer," it had my answering a different @question than the one I should have been answering, because the cache kept a memory of the instance variable on a page that I had already navigated away from.

```
<% cache @answers do %>
    <% if @answers.empty? %>
    <div class="row">
  <h5>This question hasn't been answered yet:   <% if can? :create, @answer  %>

  <% if current_user && !current_user.answers.map(&:question_id).include?(@question.id) %>
<%= link_to "Add an answer", new_question_answer_path(@question) %>
<% end %>

    <% end %> </h5>
  ....some code not included
```

How can I stop the cache from interfering with logic like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add the logic into the cache key.
So...

```
cache [@answers, current_user.answers.map...]
```

This will base the view on what the user's answer is...you may want to break down the rest into more fragment caches in addition to the above.

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify a bit more? I put the logic in the key (i.e. to act as the key), but then also repeat it where I need it in the code?

Comment: Yes, the key needs to contain the logic for what's being shown, in this case the answers and the link or no link.